# ¿Cómo adaptar un filter a un Picker en react native?

Tags: react-native

soy nuevo utilizando react native y quisiera que me ayudaran con lo siguiente:

Tengo un filtro que estoy tratando de adaptar a un picker, pero no lo he logrado, lo que tengo actualmente hace el filtro correctamente, pero en pantalla me muestra doble los generos (dos veces F, dos veces M)

¿Cómo puedo adaptar un Picker al filtro creado sin que se repitan los values (datos)?

Estoy utilizando la version de react-native 0.59, para android

```
genders = [];
this.state = {
  gender: '',
};
 getFilterData() {
//Genders
 this.genders.push({
  value: 'Masculino',
  id: 'M',
});
this.genders.push({
  value: 'Femenino',
  id: 'F',
});
}

getFilteredData = (affiliates: any[]): any[] => {

 if (this.state.gender !== "") {
   affiliateFiltered = affiliateFiltered.filter(affiliate => affiliate.gender === this.state.gender);
 }
  }
 renderFiltersContent = () => {

return (
<View style={{ paddingTop: 5}}>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 12}}>
      Género
    </Text>
      <Picker
        selectedValue={this.state.gender}
        style={{ width: '100%'}}
        onValueChange={(itemValue) =>
          this.setState({ gender: itemValue })}>
        {this.genders.map((genders, i) => {
          return <Picker.Item label={genders.value} key={i} value={genders.id} />
        })}
      </Picker>
    </View>
)
}
```